# Getting username password from UITextField iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using below code to get connected with the HTTP server. Here how would I modify my code so that the username and password would be given through input from UITextField and the same data which will be saved in NSUserDefaults will be used next time for the connection.

> NSString *urlAsString = @"http://abc.com/services/user/validate?email=abc@gmail.com&password=123456";

```
//urlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAppendingString:@"?email=abc@gmail.com"]; 
//urlAsString = [urlAsString stringByAppendingString:@"&pass=123456"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data, NSError *error) {

     if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){

         NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         NSLog(@"HTML = %@", html);

         receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

     }
     else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
         NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded."); 

     }

     else if (error != nil){
         NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);
     } }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
       @"http://abc.com/services/user/validateemail=%@&password=%@",
           myUsernameTextField.text,       // abc@gmail.com
           myPasswordTextField.text ];     // 1234565
```

Comment: thanx but now when I have tried this code it is giving errors, not getting connected

Comment: Has this ever worked?  If so, is the value of urlAsString the same as when you hardcode it?

Comment: no it does not work even a single time ... while with the previous code it works fine when we the values are being given directly and not from the textfield